# How do I make this jQuery text disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm a student and just very lost in my coding class. My teacher gave us this code to make it so when I click on a header, it expands into a paragraph.

He then wants us to make it so when you click on the header, the paragraph disappears again. I just cannot figure out how to do this second part, making it disappear.

This is what the 'Show Article' code looks like.

```
function showArticle(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
```

Can anyone help me out please? I feel like it's so simple I'm just so bad at this. If you could tell me where to place it in my code that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: You can set `display` to `"none"` to make it disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using js and not jquery

```
var visible = false;
function showArticle(id) {
  if (visible === false) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
    visible = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    visible = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: THANK YOU. you have no idea how helpful this was.

Answer (score 0):

```
function  toggleArticle(id){
($('#'+id).is(':visible') ? $('#'+id).hide() : $('#'+id).show() )}
```

Comment: jQuery has a method called `toggle` that does that: `$('#'+id).toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's toggle.

```
$('#'+headerId).on('click', function(){
    $('#'+id).toggle();
});
```